# node express aws s3.listBuckets executes call back after page is rendered

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

list Buckets with callback:

```
router.get('/', function(request,response) {
    s3.listBuckets(function(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {  
            console.log(data.Buckets[0].Name);//since i have only one bucket
            bucket = data.Buckets[0].name;     
        }
    });

    response.render('index', { mybucket:bucket });
    console.log("rendered page");
});
```

Output:

```
rendered page                      //rendered page with mybucket:'' empty
GET /getbucket 200 7.827 ms - 787
lvresults                         //bucketname displayed after rendering in console
```

bucketname is accessible only after page is rendered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should access data inside the callback function.

```
router.get('/', function(request,response) {
    s3.listBuckets(function(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {  
            console.log(data.Buckets[0].Name);
            bucket = data.Buckets[0].name;  
            console.log("rendered page"); 
            response.render('index', { mybucket:bucket });         
        }
    });   

});
```

To get more understanding about asynchronous behavior, [this link](https://blog.risingstack.com/asynchronous-javascript/) would be helpful.